# What's better for update program - GUI or console?

Tags: vb.net

I have created an update program for my project, and I'm thinking what is better - to be GUI, or to be console app?
Here's both pros and cons:

GUI: user-friendly,easy, but too much for so little program. It is unnecesseraly.

Console: Simple, but not user-friendly. And easy too!

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers! My dilemma is that the GUI is kinda too much for something so small - it will have buttons, labels, progress bars, while with console you just click, and boom. It's super easy!

Comment: So what are the requirements for user-friendliness?  If you can better define who the consumer of your program is, you will be better able to make a decision on whether a GUI or console app meets that user (or group of user's) requirements.

Comment: It's more a matter of taste and your usage scenarios. If you want user to be, say, notified of updates than nice and shiny GUI might be a plus. Otherwise, if you want to just run it as a service - then it can be console.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! My dilemma is that the GUI is kinda too much for something so small - it will have buttons, labels, progress bars, while with console you just click, and boom. It's super easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to separate the update logic from the user interface. This makes it easy to try both of them.

You could have three separate projects in one solution. One class library containing the update logic. One console program and one WinForms program, both referencing the class library.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer to that depends on exactly the questions you asked: who do you want to do most of the work, you or the user? In most cases, the answer is 'you'. It's your job as a developer to give the user a usable product.

Also, remember that you only develop once, but the user uses your program again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Just because it's a GUI doesn't mean that it has to be a complex GUI. You could have something as simple as a form with a label in it that says "Application Updating".

I personally would go the GUI route with an option for a non-interactive install (i.e. don't show the user interface form).

The reason for this approach is that at some point down the road, you may want/need additional options or user interaction and if you start with the console route, you may need to switch to GUI eventually or risk having the console UI becoming overly complicated.

For example, if you want to charge for an update because of massive improvements, or you want to have an advanced mode for the application that is purchasable, then you would probably want to obtain a key from the user to enable this. Collecting this information in a form could be much more user friendly than keying it in at the console.

You also may want to provide a hyperlink in the update form to link to the list of new features on your web site or in the install directory. Again, it would be more user friendly in a GUI.